# Python Memory Error - Sklearn Huge Input Data?

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn

I need to train the svm classifier in sklearn. The dimensions of the feature vectors go in hundreds of thousands and there are tens of thousands of such feature vectors. However, each dimension can be 0, 1 or -1. Only some 100 are non-zero in each feature vector. Any efficient way to give the info about the feature vectors to the classifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to train the svm classifier in sklearn.

You mean `sklearn.svm.SVC`? For high dimensional sparse data and many samples, `LinearSVC`, `LogisticRegression`, `PassiveAggressiveClassifier` or `SGDClassifier` can be much faster to train for comparable predictive accuracy.

> The dimensions of the feature vectors go in lakhs and there are tens of thousands of such feature vectors. However, each dimension can be 0, 1 or -1. Only some 100 are non-zero in each feature vector. Any efficient way to give the info about the feature vectors to the classifier?

Find a way to load your data as a `scipy.sparse` matrix that does not store the zeros in memory. Have a look at the [documentation on feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html). It will give you tools to do that depending on the nature of the representation of the original data.

Comment: Thanks!!!Sparse matrices worked brilliantly. However, the classifier is taking a lot of time to get trained. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please open a new question with the details: which sklearn class, what is the data shape, what is the sparsity level, how many target classes...

Comment: Note that according to documentation, your array should be c-contiguous. If you work with Pandas DataFrame, you are likely working with f-contiguous arrays. That can result in Python Memory Exception when running any scikit algorithm.